# What is the optimal way to explore the planets in Master of Orion? (Maximize $\sum_{v\in T}r(v)$ where $|T|=n$ and $T\supset S$.)

Tags: graph-theory, np-complete

The general problem is, given

1. a graph $G=(V,E)$ with vertices $V,$ and edges in $E$,
2. a path connected subset $S$ of $V$  (the previously explored planets),
3. a mapping $r:V\rightarrow (0, m)$ where $m\in\mathbb R$ ($r$ is the reward for exploring each planet), and
4. an integer $n$, where $|V|>n>|S|$ ($n$ is the number of planets to be explored),

which path connected superset $T$ of $S$ of size $n$ maximizes 
$$\sum_{v\in T}r(v)\ \ ?$$

Mainly, I would like to know if a polynomial time algorithm exists to solve this problem.

Also, in the actual game $V\subset\mathbb R^2$ and there exists an positive integer $d$ such that $e\in E$ if and only if the Euclidean distance between the vertices of $e$ is less than $d$.  Would that condition allow for a faster or simpler algorithm?

There is one more condition that is satisfied in the actual game, the incidence count for each vertex is less than 20.  (i.e. $\max_{v\in V} |\{e| v\in e\}| < 20$).  It's possible that adding that condition would allow for a polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: Yes, I was searching the literature and it does seem very similar to the knapsack problem.

Comment: This is like the knapsack problem, but the "weights" for each of the items (planets) that will go in the knapsack are all the same.  If all the weights for the items are the same, then the knapsack problem is trivial (I think).  Just grab the $n$ most valuable items where $n$ is the number of items that can fit in the knapsack.  The requirement that the solution be path connected is what makes this question harder for me.

Comment: @MorganRodgers   Now i think you are right.  We might be able to convert a knapsack problem into this problem.  Take a Knapsack problem with $n$ items with integer weights $w_i$ and value $r_i$ for $i=1,2\ldots n$.  Take $S$ to be a single vertex, then construct $n$ paths from $S$.  Make the $i$th path have length $w_i$ and each of the vertices along the path has reward 0 except the last vertex which has reward $r_i$.  Maximizing the sum of these rewards would solve the 0-1 associated knapsack problem.

Comment: Search for the term "maximum weight connected subgraph". Btw, your set S can be reduced to a single vertex of a modified graph.

Comment: @p.s.    Thank you very much.   I found this paper "Solving the Maximum-Weight Connected Subgraph Problem to Optimality"  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.5308.pdf  which seems very relevant.